# Excel CUBEMEMBER return multiple matches

Tags: excel, lambda, mdx, olap

I'm trying to create a lambda function to search and return all matching data from my datamodel, currently I have the following function:

```
LAMBDA(Table, SearchValue, SearchColumn, ReturnColumn, [ValueIfError],
LET(
    Query, CUBEMEMBER(
        "ThisWorkbookDataModel",
        "([" & Table& "].[" & SearchValue& "].&[" & SearchColumn & "],[" & Table& "].[" & ReturnColumn & "].Children)"
    ),
    IF(ISOMITTED(ValueIfError), Query, IFERROR(Query; ValueIfError))
)
```

And it works perfectly, however, it only works when there is one an just one matching reference in the search table. I wish to return an array of all matching values, is that possible?

-Update-

I found a workaround using CUBERANKEDMEMBER, which allows me to indicate which index of the returning array I want to fetch, this is not exactly what I want because I wish to perform my own operations on that return array, but is something I can work with in the meantime.